# Performance issues using task factory in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a logging system for a web application which logs a sequence of events in a dictionary object before sending it to my logging object using Task.Factory.StartNew(() => iLogEventSave()). The logger seemed to work fine, but in some instances some events were not being saved properly so I used the lock() statement to correct the issue. This seemed to do the trick, but the application's performance has dramatically decreased by doing this. How can I have the UI/Page render without having to wait for the Tasks to finish their job?

Below is the code

```
   private static readonly object Locker = new object();



    public void iLogEventSave(object state)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        IDictionary<string, string> EventDetails = (IDictionary<string, string>)state;
        string logFile = "";

        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log_File_Path"].ToString() =="")
        {
            logFile = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "Logs\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".txt";
        }
        else
        {
         logFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log_File_Path"].ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".txt";
        }



        lock (Locker)
        {
            if (File.Exists(logFile))
            {
                doc.Load(logFile);
            }
            else
            {
                var root = doc.CreateElement("Log");
                doc.AppendChild(root);

            }

            var el = (XmlElement)doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Event"));


            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in EventDetails)
            {
                XmlElement Desc = doc.CreateElement("Details");

                Desc.SetAttribute(item.Key.ToString(), item.Value);

                el.AppendChild(Desc);

            }



            doc.Save(logFile);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must provide much details.

Comment: There is no point in creating a bunch of threads, then making them all wait for a lock so that only one of them runs at a time.

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to guess what's going on.

Comment: It's difficult to know how to answer this without further details. But in general, knowing where to put a lock, and how long to keep it, is a matter of some art.

Comment: I added the code for the logger above.

Comment: The performance issues have nothing to do with Task.Factory. The task is, indeed, running asynchronously, but the lock is preventing more than one thread from writing to the file at once. If you need better logging throughput, don't use a file, use a database.

Comment: The main problem is that you are trying to rebuild the entire log instead of simply appending to it. This can't work if you have even two concurrent operations. Either append xml fragments to the file (as log4net does), or use one of the tried and tested logging libraries like log4net, NLog etc

Comment: If this code is being run in a separate Task, why would it cause slow the UI and rest of the application down? I will look into appending the XML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your log did not save several events while being executed asynchronously, you have an unhandled error that you did not address. Considering that you're using a file, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it failed because two threads were competing for access to the same log file and the first thread to grab it locked the other one out. This is why your lock would now work, it prevents other threads from trying to grab the file.

But logging to a file means that you've effectively restricted yourself to one thread at a time and dealing with the entire file as it grows. You have to load more and more, append more and more, and locking the thread means that [the more threads are waiting to log the events, the higher your overhead](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=600). All this could certainly add up to a decrease in performance.

May I recommend using a database table to log events? File I/O is very expensive, resource and time-wise. Databases have less overhead and far better throughput by comparison in these very scenarios.

Comment: Very good points. I am going to revisit the log using a database approach. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: My pleasure. Also keep in mind that databases can handle multiple threads accessing them and know how to assign primary keys correctly in this scenario so you wouldn't need a lock condition.